# Mantel-Haenzsel Test and Fisher’s Exact Test

Tags: cochran-mantel-haenszel

I am testing independence for two binary variables in the presence of a third categorical variable. I initially used Cochran-Mantel-Haenszel Test. However, the test requires all the associations for the partial tables be in the same direction. Since this requirement is violated, is there an alternative test for this? or should I use Fisher’s Exact Test per partial table?